# How do you display a message using VBScript (VBS), without causing an error?

Tags: windows, vbscript

How do you display a message in VBScript?

This results in an error message:

```
X = MsgBox("Something, Happy Fools!", 0+16, "Ha!")
```

That message was just an error one. How can I fix it?

Comment: Of course, this will be answered by showing examples and doc links which you could easily find yourself. This wastes our time, guys.

Comment: What was the error message? The OP has left the building (*"Last seen more than 7 years ago"*). Perhaps someone can reconstruct it (I don't have readily access to a Windows system)? It is OK to leave information here in comments. It will be picked up.

Comment: Or in other words, will that line in itself cause an error? Or was it pasted directly into a command line window and thus causing an error (or similar)?

Comment: Note: `0` is `vbOKOnly`. So 0+16 is trying to express `vbOKOnly` + `vbCritical`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few msgbox types out there...

**Here are some links:**

- [1: VBA Message Box (msgbox) – The Message Can Do Better](http://www.databison.com/vba-message-box-msgbox-the-message-can-do-better/)
- [2: VBA Message Box Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)
- [3: VBScript Message Box Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

**Here's the syntax:**

```
Syntax
MsgBox(prompt[, buttons] [, title] [, helpfile, context])
```

**And here's some examples:**

```
'basic
Sub basic_messagebox()
    MsgBox "Hi there"
End Sub
```

---

```
'Abort/Retry/Ignore - returns integer according to user entry.
Sub basic_messagebox()

    i = MsgBox("Do you wish to be terminated ?", vbAbortRetryIgnore, "Greetings Earthlings", "test.hlp", 100)
End Sub
```

---

```
'Yes No msgbox
Sub YesNo_msgbox
    intAnswer = Msgbox("Do you want to delete these files?", vbYesNo, "Delete Files")
    If intAnswer = vbYes Then
        Msgbox "You answered yes."
    Else
        Msgbox "You answered no."
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
'You can incrementally add on different vbelements to build the msgbox construct
Sub basic_messagebox()
    i = MsgBox("Hi there", vbOKOnly + vbCritical)
End Sub
```

---

And here's a list of **accepted vb elements in a msgbox.**

[image]

Comment: That was Visual Basic and I was using VBScript! (.vbs)

Comment: Nah this is vbscript, vba and visual basic.

Comment: put one of this in notepad and save it as something.vbs and see if it works.

Comment: If you want msgbox to appear via vbs file. You will need to activate it through the wscript.exe application so it runs as a windows form.

Answer (score 0):

The MsgBox method is precisely how you accomplish it in VBScript. Use either of these syntax varieties:

```
msgbox "hello", 0+16, "foo"
```

or

```
call msgbox("hello", 0+16, "foo")
```

Comment: I was using VBScript!

Comment: Do you realize that VBS stands for "Visual Basic Script?" as in VBS?