# How do i make a msgbox that has 2 Options that do different Things?

Tags: vbscript

I dont currently know how to make this so I need help at fixing it

I made this and I'm quiet stupid at vbscripting I guess

I expected that to work but it didnt worked at all

```
Dim main

Main=msgBox("Do you want open the Learning Programm?", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion, "Aktivate the Programm")

If

    vbYes then

    Y=msgBox("Are you Sure?", vbQuestion + vbInformation, "Yes or No") then do 

        Wscript CreateObject("Wscript.Sc")

ElseIf

    vbNo or vbCancel then 

    X=msgBox("Are you Sure to leave?", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion, "Exit Learning Programm")

    if

        vbNo or vbCancel then 

        vbDefaultButton3 and then Return

        Main

ElseIf

    vbYes then do Nothing
```

Comment: "I havent found what i wanted to do so i asked" ._.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you display a message using VBScript (VBS), without causing an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644032/how-do-you-display-a-message-using-vbscript-vbs-without-causing-an-error)

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to learn VBScript first step by step. You can't simply throw stuff at the wall and hope it sticks. That doesn't work for programming. Programming languages have a specified syntax, where if you don't follow that, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Im fine with your awnser and yes i should have looked somewhere to learn it but i already did Things in Vbs like making a msgBox that opens as often as i want so i wanted to make something cool